# Pre defining and pre populating a field in Couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am trying to pre define and possibly pre populate a field in CouchDB every time a new document is created by the user. That is until a user enters a different value the initial value that I created will stay.
According to this article it is not possible to do so:  ([CouchDB: Pre-filled fields when adding new documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937655/couchdb-pre-filled-fields-when-adding-new-documents)) 
I was just wondering if there was an update to this. Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Update handler is the most up to date way to pre-defined a document on the server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CouchDB: Pre-filled fields when adding new documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937655/couchdb-pre-filled-fields-when-adding-new-documents)